# Parsing a Two level - array, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

**What I have**

I have two-level array as follows:

```
<?php $myarray = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [3] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
  [4] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
  [5] => Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) 
  [6] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [7] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [8] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [9] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [10] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [11] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [12] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [13] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
  [14] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [color] => red ) 
  [15] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [color] => yellow ) 
  [16] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [color] => yellow ) 
  [17] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [color] => yellow ) 
  [18] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [color] => red ) 
  [19] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [color] => yellow ) 
  [20] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [color] => yellow ) 
  [21] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [color] => yellow ) 
  [22] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [color] => yellow ) 
  [23] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [color] => yellow ) 
  [24] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [color] => yellow ) 
  [25] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [color] => red ) 
  [26] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [color] => yellow ) 
) ?>
```

The Inner arrays (index 0 - 26 ) contain 4 or 5 entries  each corresponding to positions 1,2,3,4 and entry 5 which can be red, yellow or green. A position can be  0 or  1.

**What I want to do:**

1) I want to add all values at position 1, position 2, position 3 and position 4 of the inner arrays (Total of a column )

2) If any inner array has more than one "position" that is 1, the whole  "row" (entry) needs to be flagged and  "unset from $myarray

If it is not clear, please ask some more and I will try my best to clarify.

Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Parsing the array. Lol

Comment: Seems are are trigger happy to just down rate anything, huh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

total of a column is pretty simple by using array_sum() combined with array_column():

```
$position1Sum = array_sum(array_column($myarray,'1'));
$position2Sum = array_sum(array_column($myarray,'2'));
$position3Sum = array_sum(array_column($myarray,'3'));
$position4Sum = array_sum(array_column($myarray,'4'));
```

to clean the array of anything with more than one position active:

```
/* editing the same array you are looping thru is typically bad - lets make a copy first.*/
$cleanArray = $myarray;
/* loop thru - and unset the rows where more than one position are 1 
(which will make their sum more than 1) */
foreach($myarray as $key => $value){
    if($value[1] + $value[2] + $value[3] +$value[4] > 1){
        unset($cleanArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

$cleanArray will now contain the same contents as $myarray, minus the rows that have more than one position set to 1.  Of course there are several other ways to potentially tackle this - I try to stick to the cleanest to read later if possible...  :-)

Comment: Did what I needed mate. Thanks a lot